# Proving $\lim_{x\to9}\sqrt x=3$ using Cauchy's definition

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

> Prove: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to9}\sqrt x=3$ using Cauchy's definition for a limit.

After doing the scratch work I get that: $\delta=\epsilon^2+6\epsilon$, so going back, I have to show that $|x-9|<\delta\Rightarrow |\sqrt x -3|<\epsilon$.

So we have: $\epsilon^2+6\epsilon-9<x<\epsilon^2+6\epsilon+9 \iff \epsilon^2+6\epsilon-9<x<(\epsilon+3)^2$ but what about the left side of the inequality? How can I simplify it to $(\epsilon-3)^2$?

**Edit:** if $\delta=3\epsilon$ then how can you justify the move from: $3\epsilon-9<x<3\epsilon +9$ to $\epsilon-3<\sqrt x<\epsilon +3$?

Comment: I don't think you can. I'd look again at the choice of $\delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can use

$$|\sqrt{x} - 3| = \frac{|x-9|}{\sqrt{x}+3}\leqslant\frac{|x-9|}{3}.$$

Comment: Alright so $\delta=3\epsilon$ but I get stuck with it as well... $3\epsilon-9<x<3\epsilon +9$ now what?

Comment: If $|x-9| < \delta = 3\epsilon$ then $|\sqrt{x} - 3| < \epsilon$.

Comment: But this has to be shown, how can you go from: $3\epsilon-9<x<3\epsilon +9$ to $\epsilon-3<\sqrt x<\epsilon +3$ ?

Comment: Pick any $\epsilon > 0$.  You have to find an appropriate $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$. If $|x-9| < \delta$ then $|x-9|/3 < \delta/3$. Now $|\sqrt{x}-3| < |x-9|/3 \implies |\sqrt{x}-3| < \delta/3$. Take $\delta = 3\epsilon$.

Comment: @kuhaku: You're very welcome.

Comment: It's not $3\epsilon-9<x$, it is $9-3\epsilon<x$. @kuhaku

Answer (score 1):

Your $\delta$ doesn't work: if $\varepsilon=1/2$ then $\delta=1/4+3=13/4$. Then take $x=6$ which satisfies $\lvert x-9\rvert=3<\delta$, yet we have:
$\bigl\lvert\sqrt{6}-3\bigr\rvert\approx0.55>\varepsilon$.

There's a much simpler $\delta$ to choose…